# How to stay Focus in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

code:-

```
const handleKeyDown = (event, ID) => {
  const active = document.activeElement;
        active.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

            switch (event.key) {
                case "ArrowUp":
                    active?.previousElementSibling?.focus();
                    break;
                case "ArrowDown":
                    active?.nextElementSibling?.focus();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
        })        
    }

  <tr key={playdata.idx} tabIndex={playdata.idx} className="border_bottom"
              onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, playdata.idx)}>
                                    <td style={{ color: "white", width: "200px" }}>
                                        <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`} alt="Clip Thumbnail" width="50%" />
                                    </td>
```

When I click the row it shows me the focus and I can do the navigation with up and down but when I click the outside the row focus is gone.
I want when the user clicks outside the row/table it stays focused where the focuses left
How to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `activeElement`, we just reuse it for `document.click` which is to listen to all areas' clicks and filter them out with your expected areas (in your case, the expected elements are `.border_bottom`)

```
let active = document.activeElement; //this variable should be global to state your previous active element

document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
//if the current clicked element has your expected class, we should assign a new active element
  if(event.target.classList.contains("border_bottom")){ //you can add another class for the check instead of `border_bottom`
     active = event.target; //set a new active element
  }
  //focus only on active elements
  active?.focus();
});
```